# Pandas: How to fill in null values from columns in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a dataframe where certain essential columns are NULL (that I need for further machine learning work). I have another dataframe with similar data from where I want to pull in the missing values from.

For example, `df1` is the main dataframe

```
id     col1    col2     col3     col4    col5
1      A       AA       100      5.0     0.9
2      A       BB       150      4.2     0.5
3      A       CC       100      NaN     NaN
4      B       AA       300      NaN     NaN
5      B       BB       100      NaN     NaN
6      C       BB       50       3.4     0.6
```

The dataframe that I want to fill those `NaN` columns in `col4` and `col5` could be like

```
id     col1    col3     col4    col5
100      A     100      4.5     1.0
101      A     100      3.5     0.8
103      B     300      5.0     0.5
105      B     300      5.5     0.8
106      B     100      5.3     0.2
107      C     100      3.0     1.2
```

So, I don't have `col2` in the second df and there are duplicates for the `col1` and `col2` columns that I can merge by. So, I have to choose the value with the maximum `col4` value to fill the corresponding values in `df1`.

For example, the correct value for `df1` after filling in the data would be:

```
id     col1    col2     col3     col4    col5
1      A       AA       100      5.0     0.9
1      A       BB       150      4.2     0.5
1      A       CC       100      4.5     1.0
1      B       AA       300      5.5     0.8
1      B       BB       100      5.3     0.2
1      C       BB       50       3.4     0.6
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Does the maximum value in `col5` always occur in the same rows as the maximum values in `col4`?

Comment: @unutbu no not necessarily

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df1.combine_first(
    df1.merge(
        df2.drop('id', 1).ix[df2.groupby(['col1', 'col3']).col4.idxmax()],
        on=['col1', 'col3'], how='left', suffixes=['_', '']
    )[['col4', 'col5']]
).reindex_axis(df1.columns, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'col2': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'], 'col3': [100, 150, 100, 300, 100, 50], 'col4': [5.0, 4.2, nan, nan, nan, 3.4], 'col5': [0.9, 0.5, nan, nan, nan, 0.6], 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'col3': [100, 100, 300, 300, 100, 100], 'col4': [4.5, 3.5, 5.0, 5.5, 5.3, 3.0], 'col5': [1.0, 99, 0.5, 0.8, 0.2, 1.2], 'id': [100, 101, 103, 105, 106, 107]})

df2_max = df2.drop('id', axis=1).groupby(['col1','col3']).max()
df3 = pd.merge(df1[['col1','col3']], df2_max, 
               left_on=['col1','col3'], right_index=True, how='left')
result = df1.combine_first(df3)
```

yields

```
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5  id
0    A   AA   100   5.0   0.9   1
1    A   BB   150   4.2   0.5   2
2    A   CC   100   4.5  99.0   3
3    B   AA   300   5.5   0.8   4
4    B   BB   100   5.3   0.2   5
5    C   BB    50   3.4   0.6   6
```

---

First, [find the max of `df2`'s `col4` and `col5` columns for each value of `col1`,`col3`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
df2_max = df2.drop('id', axis=1).groupby(['col1','col3']).max()
#            col4  col5
# col1 col3            
# A    100    4.5  99.0
# B    100    5.3   0.2
#      300    5.5   0.8
# C    100    3.0   1.2
```

Notice the 99 in the first row (instead of 0.8). I changed the example
slightly, to show that the `col4` maximum need not occur in the same row as the
`col5` maximum.

Next, [merge `df1` and `df2_max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), on `df1`'s `col1`,`col3` columns, and `df2`'s index:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1[['col1','col3']], df2_max, 
               left_on=['col1','col3'], right_index=True, how='left')
#   col1  col3  col4  col5
# 0    A   100   4.5  99.0
# 1    A   150   NaN   NaN
# 2    A   100   4.5  99.0
# 3    B   300   5.5   0.8
# 4    B   100   5.3   0.2
# 5    C    50   NaN   NaN
```

This provides us with the maximums in `col4` and `col5` in a DataFrame whose index matches `df1`'s index. This allows us to use [`df1.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to fill in the NaNs with values from `df3`:

```
result = df1.combine_first(df3)
```